# Upload file into public repository GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to upload file into public repository Github, in order people can download my source... 
Can you help me?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have git installed on your machine and created a github repository

open terminal/cmd

**cd /path/to/image/directory**

follow the command below

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Upload images"
git remote add origin https://github.com/your-git-repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

sample of image source from gihub
https://github.com/PenAndPapers/AngularWebPortfolio/blob/master/client/assets/images/header-bg.jpg